# Rails 3: Updating Database Data

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system/wiki/Migrate-to-Version-2.0). The final step is to update my database data by using this line of code:

```
UPDATE rs_reputation_messages SET sender_type = 'ReputationSystem::Evaluation' WHERE sender_type = 'RSEvaluation'
```

I can't figure out where to put this code. Typically, I'd update the database with a migration, but this looks like a MySQL command. I'm certain there's a very, very simple answer to this question, but despite scouring Google, I can't even figure out how to phrase the question right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always better to create a migration file in such cases. you can use [`update_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001798) method

```
RsReputationMessages.update_all("sender_type = 'ReputationSystem::Evaluation'", 
                                "sender_type = 'RSEvaluation'")
```

OR

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE rs_reputation_messages 
                                       SET sender_type = 'ReputationSystem::Evaluation' 
                                       WHERE sender_type = 'RSEvaluation'")
```